# How to replace activity intent extra?

Tags: android, android-intent

My app can be open by push.

```
   val intentToMainActivity = Intent().apply {
      action = "action"
      type = "text/plain"
      flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
      putExtra("EXTRA_KEY", moduleCode)
   }
```

I get moduleCode from FirebaseService and open needed fragment depending this moduleCode.
But I don't know how to remove extra by name "EXTRA_KEY".

I tried to remove extra when activity destroyed

```
   override fun onDestroy() {
      intent.extras?.remove("EXTRA_KEY")
   }
```

but it doesn't work. System always remember the first writing extra by "EXTRA_KEY".

Please help me to clear my intent

I saw many answers but it didn't help

Comment: intentToMainActivity.putExtra("EXTRA_KEY", null)
   }

Comment: intent=intent.extras?.remove("EXTRA_KEY") But i dont understand what you want. If the activity is destroyed the intent is destroyed too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to remove the extra data from an intent, but modifying an existing intent in that way isn't supported. Once you set an extra in an intent, it cannot be removed. The intent you create in your val intentToMainActivity is a separate instance, and removing extras from it won't affect the intent that started your activity.

If you want to remove or clear an extra when your activity is destroyed, you can do that by saving the value in a member variable within your activity and then setting it to null in the onDestroy method.

Here's how you can do it:

```
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var moduleCode: String? = null // Initialize it with null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    moduleCode = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_KEY")
```